# How to reference all UITextfields in a view? Swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to reference multiple UITextfields in a view. If any of the textfields are empty I want an alert to pop up. How do I reference all the textfields at once to check if any of them are empty?

I have the following code to check the fields individually, but I'm trying to check them all at once.

```
if (firstName.text?.isEmpty)!{
     fieldAlert()
}else{
     runMutation()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an outlet collection like and hook all textfields to it

```
@IBOutlet weak var allTexs:[UITextField]!
```

Then

```
let em = allTexs.filter { $0.text == "" }.count
if em == 0 {
  print("All ok")
}
else {
  print("Some or all empty")
}
```

You can also

```
let allTexs = view.subviews.filter { $0 is UITextField }
```

Comment: maybe you can add a type checking implemention with using all subviews checking, it has not to be wired with IBOutlet I think.

Comment: yes but this needs them  to be direct childs of view , or use `viewWithTag` instead

Comment: Worked perfectly!